# Spring Boot graphiql not working when running a Jar but works on IntelliJ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-graphql

I have a basic spring boot 2.7 project with graphql.

I can access the /graphiql  console from the path  http://localhost:8080/graphiql?path=/graphql when running the project on intellij but I get 404 when running a jar file.

Comment: This should work.. How do you start your app via the console? `java -jar your-graphql-app.jar`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly  how I run my app.   Also, I forgot to mention that I am using spring webflux.

Comment: Is graphiql enabled? via application.properties `spring.graphql.graphiql.enabled=true`?

Comment: Aha! I was missing that part.  Its working now.

Answer (score 1):

GraphiQL is not enabled by default and this needs to be activated using `spring.graphql.graphiql.enabled=true`.

Your application is probably using devtools, which enables GraphiQL for development purposes. See [Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/web.html#web.graphql.graphiql).

Comment: Thanks pointing this out. Its now working after  adding  spring.graphql.graphiql.enabled=true on the  application.properties. Thank you.