# GraphiQL is not working in my spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, graphiql

i'm using Spring For GraphQL dependency to work with graphql with my spring boot
application, but when i run the app the expected behavior is the noted [in here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/web.html#web.graphql.graphiql).

I evidently placed the property in the application.properties like this:
`spring.graphql.graphiql.enabled=true`

i saw a similar problem [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70597180/spring-boot-graphiql-not-working-when-running-a-jar-but-works-on-intellij#:%7E:text=GraphiQL%20is%20not%20enabled%20by,enabled%3Dtrue%20.), but using devtools or not, when i run the application either in jar file or in debug mode graphiql is not working, i would appreciate an answer.

Comment: Is <spring.graphql.graphiql.enabled> set as true?

Comment: yer it is enabled

Comment: 1. Please add pom.xml and application.properties here for mor clarity. 2. Is your app's endpoint working (like from postman)?